# aws step function set resource data using cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

Hi I am creating a step function using python cdk and my step function code look like this :

```
state_machine = sfn.StateMachine(
    self,
    "MyStateMachine",
    definition=tasks.LambdaInvoke(
        self,
        "MyLambdaTask",
        lambda_function=hello_function
    ).next(
        sfn.Succeed(
            self,
            "GreetedWorld"
        )
    )
)
```

and here just I want to add this configurations to wait for token using python cdk:

as I added this configuration on aws dashboard directly in edit state machine json

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
```

want to add this line of code using python cdk . can't find way to add this

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to invoke your Lambda function asynchronously and wait for the response token.

To do this in CDK, you can [specify the integration type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#integrationpattern) for the `LambdaInvoke` action, as well as pass the token to the handler:

```
state_machine = sfn.StateMachine(
    self,
    "MyStateMachine",
    definition=tasks.LambdaInvoke(
        self,
        "MyLambdaTask",
        lambda_function=hello_function,
        integration_pattern=tasks.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
        payload={"token.$":"$$.Task.Token"},
    ).next(
        sfn.Succeed(
            self,
            "GreetedWorld"
        )
    )
)
```

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#integrationpattern

Comment: reopening because getting this  `Task Token is required in `payload` for callback. Use JsonPath.taskToken to set the token.`
`

Comment: I am sending payload this way    {"payload.$": "$",
                    "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                    "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"}

Comment: and I am getting execution id and job_id from payload .